# Check if Dictionary/List Item Exists Using a Long Index

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am attempting to parse data from a large JSON-like Python dictionary that I received from Musicbrainz using the `musicbrainzngs` module. Below is a sample of this type of dictionary in a pretty format.

```
{ 'artist-credit': [ { 'artist': { 'id': '0039c7ae-e1a7-4a7d-9b49-0cbc716821a6',
                                   'name': 'Death Cab for Cutie',
                                   'sort-name': 'Death Cab for Cutie'}}],
  'artist-credit-phrase': 'Death Cab for Cutie',
  'asin': 'B0000D1FDI',
  'barcode': '655173103227',
  'country': 'US',
  'cover-art-archive': { 'artwork': 'true',
                         'back': 'false',
                         'count': '1',
                         'front': 'true'},
  'date': '2003-10-07',
  'id': 'e602a3ae-fe8f-4abd-8638-f055517bacb2',
  'label-info-count': 1,
  'label-info-list': [ { 'catalog-number': 'bark32',
                         'label': { 'id': 'a4f904e0-f048-4c13-88ec-f9f31f3e6109',
                                    'name': 'Barsuk Records',
                                    'sort-name': 'Barsuk Records'}}],
  'medium-count': 1,
  'medium-list': [ { 'disc-count': 4,
                     'disc-list': [ { 'id': '5G2zzIza.oA1Y3XpMHxuohbzazQ-',
                                      'offset-count': 11,
                                      'offset-list': [ 150,
                                                       18780,
                                                       34698,
                                                       51295,
                                                       70286,
                                                       80376,
                                                       100160,
                                                       135944,
                                                       152723,
                                                       166122,
                                                       191235],
                                      'sectors': '207432'},
                                    { 'id': '8XGkh_GqZPv6rL8W1c6_t9fQKhw-',
                                      'offset-count': 11,
                                      'offset-list': [ 150,
                                                       18933,
                                                       35005,
                                                       51755,
                                                       70899,
                                                       81142,
                                                       101079,
                                                       137017,
                                                       153949,
                                                       167501,
                                                       192767],
                                      'sectors': '208967'},
                                    { 'id': 'AptsPDTKO.nMoE_GRmqGZSWjT7g-',
                                      'offset-count': 11,
                                      'offset-list': [ 150,
                                                       18635,
                                                       34405,
                                                       50855,
                                                       69697,
                                                       79638,
                                                       99273,
                                                       134905,
                                                       151535,
                                                       164791,
                                                       189759],
                                      'sectors': '205963'},
                                    { 'id': 'scc32yarsl41ysxMw43_1Pk8n3M-',
                                      'offset-count': 11,
                                      'offset-list': [ 150,
                                                       18628,
                                                       34394,
                                                       50839,
                                                       69678,
                                                       79616,
                                                       99248,
                                                       134880,
                                                       151507,
                                                       164754,
                                                       189715],
                                      'sectors': '205910'}],
                     'format': 'CD',
                     'position': '1',
                     'track-count': 11,
                     'track-list': [ { 'id': 'd65135d9-d917-3c04-9a3e-1a9f3f75dbdf',
                                       'length': '246400',
                                       'number': '1',
                                       'position': '1',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '2aefb5c8-f137-4289-b9f9-e78d23695468',
                                                      'length': '246400',
                                                      'title': 'The New '
                                                               'Year'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '246400'},
                                     { 'id': 'bdff5634-4743-3957-9a2c-285af885fd56',
                                       'length': '210240',
                                       'number': '2',
                                       'position': '2',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '60d3363b-7cc4-4675-a85b-692683054ff2',
                                                      'length': '210213',
                                                      'title': 'Lightness'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '210240'},
                                     { 'id': '41aec2a4-4ecb-30c0-9052-099a504c1623',
                                       'length': '219280',
                                       'number': '3',
                                       'position': '3',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '6c077d47-09ae-4059-b025-d48f48710f92',
                                                      'length': '219000',
                                                      'title': 'Title '
                                                               'and '
                                                               'Registration'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '219280'},
                                     { 'id': 'b28ef069-7bca-3a43-a3a2-dcd123652d2e',
                                       'length': '251200',
                                       'number': '4',
                                       'position': '4',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '143b3d2e-82d6-4fbc-afd4-5ac8b8e2ffe6',
                                                      'length': '251187',
                                                      'title': 'Expo ’86'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '251200'},
                                     { 'id': 'c329e654-8866-3a78-939d-3cb8368f1de6',
                                       'length': '132520',
                                       'number': '5',
                                       'position': '5',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '59403f9d-722a-48c3-aedb-6c1bb6102668',
                                                      'length': '132520',
                                                      'title': 'The '
                                                               'Sound '
                                                               'of '
                                                               'Settling'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '132520'},
                                     { 'id': '469bbe0a-8ac9-38f9-8998-17ab0bdd8cb4',
                                       'length': '261773',
                                       'number': '6',
                                       'position': '6',
                                       'recording': { 'id': 'a594b2c7-5e4f-4e81-9cda-91bab05da25e',
                                                      'length': '261773',
                                                      'title': 'Tiny '
                                                               'Vessels'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '261773'},
                                     { 'id': '9ac716d8-e9a2-3b7f-9588-ef5b91b00925',
                                       'length': '475120',
                                       'number': '7',
                                       'position': '7',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '9472186f-ec6d-48d1-9a47-4bc6e922cffe',
                                                      'length': '475093',
                                                      'title': 'Transatlanticism'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '475120'},
                                     { 'id': 'a37ec190-9dde-3c23-8d2d-a561afe56a3a',
                                       'length': '221706',
                                       'number': '8',
                                       'position': '8',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '6dfcacb8-f767-43af-9645-9c9dd39eeb44',
                                                      'length': '221706',
                                                      'title': 'Passenger '
                                                               'Seat'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '221706'},
                                     { 'id': '46eecfc9-e7a3-3d73-acb1-02a5b13d3831',
                                       'length': '176640',
                                       'number': '9',
                                       'position': '9',
                                       'recording': { 'id': 'e2a42ced-3f08-4012-ad7c-8c215da8a2a1',
                                                      'length': '176640',
                                                      'title': 'Death '
                                                               'of an '
                                                               'Interior '
                                                               'Decorator'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '176640'},
                                     { 'id': 'b3e21529-72fb-30bd-b4b8-22e7c7c9a411',
                                       'length': '332826',
                                       'number': '10',
                                       'position': '10',
                                       'recording': { 'id': '70cf7264-1053-4afc-ace8-81cd24cc6391',
                                                      'length': '332826',
                                                      'title': 'We '
                                                               'Looked '
                                                               'Like '
                                                               'Giants'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '332826'},
                                     { 'id': '8b3e26c5-978b-35f2-8b2b-7e2574ae37bf',
                                       'length': '215294',
                                       'number': '11',
                                       'position': '11',
                                       'recording': { 'id': 'a9f6ea4c-06a9-46a4-9a67-667617b0fe6a',
                                                      'length': '216000',
                                                      'title': 'A Lack '
                                                               'of Color'},
                                       'track_or_recording_length': '215294'}]}],
  'packaging': 'Jewel Case',
  'quality': 'normal',
  'release-event-count': 1,
  'release-event-list': [ { 'area': { 'id': '489ce91b-6658-3307-9877-795b68554c98',
                                      'iso-3166-1-code-list': ['US'],
                                      'name': 'United States',
                                      'sort-name': 'United States'},
                            'date': '2003-10-07'}],
  'status': 'Official',
  'text-representation': {'language': 'eng', 'script': 'Latn'},
  'title': 'Transatlanticism'}
```

I am trying to parse specific bits of information out of this dictionary. For example, I have the following dictionary which is filled with general descriptions of the data as keys, and then long indexes through lists and dictionaries leading to the data I want. For this example, assume the *release_dict* is the data from above.

```
album_info = {
    "album_title": release_dict['title'],
    "album_artist": release_dict['artist-credit'][0]['artist']['name'],
    "artist": release_dict['artist-credit'][0]['artist']['name'],
    "release_date": release_dict['date'],
    "track_total": release_dict['medium-list'][disc_number]['track-count'],
    "release_label": release_dict['label-info-list'][0]['label']['name'],
}
```

The problem is, the data passed back from `musicbrainzngs` is not always the same. For example, the indexes leading to the "release_label" may not even exist. The only reasonable way I can think of handling this is to make *try* statements for every single tag like so:

```
album_dict = {}

try:
    album_dict["album_title"] = release_dict['title']
except KeyError:
    print("Value for 'album_title' not found.")
```

and do the same for all of the other tags. But I would really prefer to loop over each tag somehow to make the code more DRY and safe.

The only solution I can think of is making a function which reads an index string (i.e. `"['artist-credit'][0]['artist']['name']"`) and it would read it over and check each part for whether it exists, but I think that could be a little overkill for this problem.

Anyways, I just want to make a piece of code that gets as much information out of the raw metadata as possible. If you have any ideas, I'm open to all soultions. And thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a function that takes a variable number of keys, and stops and returns a default value if it doesn't exist (Like a nested `dict.get`).

```
def rec_get(d, *items, default=None):
    try:
        for item in items:
            d = d[item]
    except (KeyError, TypeError):
        return default
    return d

album_info = {
    "album_title": release_dict.get('title'),
    "album_artist": rec_get(release_dict, 'artist-credit', 0, 'artist', 'name'),
    "artist": rec_get(release_dict, 'artist-credit', 0, 'artist', 'name'),
    "release_date": release_dict.get('date'),
    "track_total": rec_get(release_dict, 'medium-list', disc_number, 'track-count'),
    "release_label": rec_get(release_dict, 'label-info-list', 0, 'label', 'name'),
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for.